# Get a error missing modules on the terminal

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to make a new project running `npm install -g create-react-app` on the folder directory. After doing this I get the following error:

```
module.js:487
throw err;
^

Error: Cannot find module '../package.json'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:485:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:437:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:513:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js:30:15
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js:92:3)
    at Module._compile (module.js:569:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:503:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:466:12)
```

Comment: What does your package.json look like?

Answer (score 2):

Your question is not very precise. You should give more details about what you are doing.

Still, here are some suggestions. Make sure:

- You run the command from within the folder, where your package.json is located.
- If you have not created a package.json yet, run `npm init`
- Your package.json is a valid format and readable

Comment: thank for you answer, I try to make new project with react..I run this command you said npm init..but still giving the same comment.